# How to use map in rxjs/operator

Tags: angular

API call returns data as list of `IAthing` and I would like to map to List of `Select2OptionData`

```
[
    {
        "prop1": 'vbn',
        "prop2": 'abc'
    },
    {
        "prop1": 'fgh',
        "prop2": 'tyyty'
    }
]
```

In this method from `service` file I get this error:

> `[ts] Type 'Observable<Select2OptionData>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Select2OptionData[]>'`

```
 getMethod(
    term: string = '',
    page: number = 0
  ): Observable<Select2OptionData[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(`/api/something/foobar?q=${term}&page=${page}`)
      .pipe(
        map((data: IAthing) => {
          return <Select2OptionData>{ id: data.prop1.toString(),
             text: data.prop2 };
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

`Select2OptionData` interface

```
export interface Select2OptionData {
    id: string;
    text: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
    children?: Array<Select2OptionData>;
    additional?: any;
}

export interface IAthing {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here

Comment: You say the API call returns a list of `ITag` but then you use `IAthing` in your code. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a signature error.

You expect

```
Observable<Select2OptionData[]>
```

Which is an array of objects, but you return

```
<Select2OptionData>{ id: data.prop1.toString(),
         text: data.prop2 }
```

Which is an object. Either change your map function, or your signature.

To return an array :

```
.pipe(
  map(response => response.map(item => ({ id: item.prop1, text: item.prop2 })))
)
```

Comment: I'm struck how to return data as list of objects, could you please provide code how to do it?

Comment: Sure, just edit your question with the response of your HTTP call

Answer (score -1):

You can write pipe function as follows:

```
getMethod(
term: string = '',
page: number = 0
): Observable<Select2OptionData[]> {
return this.http.get(`/api/something/foobar?q=${term}&page=${page}`)
  .pipe(
  .map(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleErrorObservable));

}
```

Handle error and data here

```
 // if get successful response extract response
 private extractData(res: Response) {
 if (res.status === 200) {
  const body = res.json();
  return body;
  } else {
  return {};
  }
}

private handleErrorObservable(error: any) {
   // 401 - unAuthorized
   if (error) {
     return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
   }
   else {
      return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
    }

  }
```